# Execute an action which protected by Spring Security in Grails

Tags: grails, spring-security, gsp

I need to do an action protected by Spring Security in Grails.
This is a gsp-view where required controller is call:

```
<g:form class="form-signin" controller="VisitorSpace">
  <g:hiddenField name="cafeeName" value="${cafeeName.cafeeName}" />
  <g:actionSubmit value="Reserve"  action="makeReserve" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Reserve</g:actionSubmit>
</g:form>
```

This is a makeReserve-action in VisitorSpaceController:

```
@Secured(['ROLE_VISITOR'])
    def makeReserve(params){
        ...
}
```

I want to execute this action from the form above when I non-registered in Spring Security. Of cause, it must be execute with registration before, in this case. But when I register, an index-action of VisitorSpaceController executes, not makeReserve. How to fix it?

Comment: You fix it by not securing the action with a role that a non-user / visitor doesn't have.

Comment: @Gregg, So I'll lose access to action if I'll change the role and be execute action with visitor's and non-user's privilegies.